# JS How to execute stdio operations and Ui operations from same js file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, electron

I am trying to do two tasks in main.js of Electron app
1) Listen standard io ports and reply when app gets message.
2) Load UI (index.js)

Part (1) or (2) works fine individually, but if I try to execute them at a time from main.js, they do not work.

Please let me know the way to execute them together.

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

/************ PART 1 *********************************************/

function nativeMessageReply()
{
var nativeMessage = require('chrome-native-messaging');

process.stdin
.pipe(new nativeMessage.Input())
.pipe(new nativeMessage.Transform(function (msg, push, done) {
  var reply = getReplyFor(msg); // Implemented elsewhere by you.
  push(reply);                  // Push as many replies as you like.
  done();                       // Call when done pushing replies.
}))
.pipe(new nativeMessage.Output())
.pipe(process.stdout)
;
}

function getReplyFor(msg)
{
    return "Reply from native";
}

/*********** PART 2 *****************************/

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()

    // How to call this on seperate thread ?
    nativeMessageReply()
  }
})
```